# exitprompt.cpp:268:22: error: passing ‘const ExitPrompter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to modify some C++ code but I and getting the following errors during build:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/runner/work/mythtv/mythtv/mythtv/programs/mythlcdserver'
cd mythshutdown/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/runner/work/mythtv/mythtv/mythtv/programs/mythshutdown/mythshutdown.pro QMAKE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake ) && make -f Makefile 
exitprompt.cpp: In member function ‘void ExitPrompter::Confirm(MythPower::Feature) const’:
Makefile:4570: recipe for target 'obj/exitprompt.o' failed
exitprompt.cpp:268:22: error: passing ‘const ExitPrompter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/runner/work/mythtv/mythtv/mythtv/programs/mythfrontend'
           DoHalt(true);
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'sub-mythfrontend-make_first' failed
                      ^
exitprompt.cpp:39:6: note:   in call to ‘void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(bool)’
 void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(const bool Confirmed)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
exitprompt.cpp:270:24: error: passing ‘const ExitPrompter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
           DoReboot(true);
                        ^
exitprompt.cpp:70:6: note:   in call to ‘void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(bool)’
 void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(const bool Confirmed)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
exitprompt.cpp:272:25: error: passing ‘const ExitPrompter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
           DoSuspend(true);
                         ^
exitprompt.cpp:100:6: note:   in call to ‘void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(bool)’
 void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(const bool Confirmed)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [obj/exitprompt.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sub-mythfrontend-make_first] Error 2
```

The code is as follows:

```
// Qt
#include <QCoreApplication>

// MythTV
#include "config.h"
#include "exitprompt.h"
#include "mythcontext.h"
#include "mythdialogbox.h"
#include "mythmainwindow.h"
#include "mythscreenstack.h"
#include "mythsystemlegacy.h"
#include "mythlogging.h"
#include "exitcodes.h"

ExitPrompter::ExitPrompter()
    : m_power(MythPower::AcquireRelease(this, true)),
      m_haltCommand(gCoreContext->GetSetting("HaltCommand", "")),
      m_rebootCommand(gCoreContext->GetSetting("RebootCommand", "")),
      m_suspendCommand(gCoreContext->GetSetting("SuspendCommand", ""))
{
}

ExitPrompter::~ExitPrompter()
{
    if (m_power)
        MythPower::AcquireRelease(this, false);
}

void ExitPrompter::DoQuit()
{
    qApp->exit();
}

void ExitPrompter::ConfirmHalt() const
{
    Confirm(MythPower::FeatureShutdown);
}

void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(const bool Confirmed)
{
    if (!Confirmed)
        return;

    // Use user specified command if it exists
    if (!m_haltCommand.isEmpty())
    {
        uint ret = myth_system(m_haltCommand);
        if (ret == GENERIC_EXIT_OK)
            return;

        LOG(VB_GENERAL, LOG_ERR,
            "User defined HaltCommand failed, falling back to "
            "alternative methods.");
    }

    // Otherwise use MythPower
    if (m_power && m_power->IsFeatureSupported(MythPower::FeatureShutdown))
        if (m_power->RequestFeature(MythPower::FeatureShutdown))
            return;

    // halt of last resort
    myth_system("sudo /sbin/halt -p");
}

void ExitPrompter::ConfirmReboot() const
{
    Confirm(MythPower::FeatureRestart);
}

void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(const bool Confirmed)
{
    if (!Confirmed)
        return;

    if (!m_rebootCommand.isEmpty())
    {
        uint ret = myth_system(m_rebootCommand);
        if (ret == GENERIC_EXIT_OK)
            return;

        LOG(VB_GENERAL, LOG_ERR,
            "User defined RebootCommand failed, falling back to "
            "alternative methods.");
    }

    // Otherwise use MythPower
    if (m_power && m_power->IsFeatureSupported(MythPower::FeatureRestart))
        if (m_power->RequestFeature(MythPower::FeatureRestart))
            return;

    // reboot of last resort
    myth_system("sudo /sbin/reboot");
}

void ExitPrompter::ConfirmSuspend(void) const
{
    Confirm(MythPower::FeatureSuspend);
}

void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(const bool Confirmed)
{
    if (!Confirmed)
        return;

    // Use user specified command if it exists
    if (!m_suspendCommand.isEmpty())
    {
        uint ret = myth_system(m_suspendCommand);
        if (ret == GENERIC_EXIT_OK)
            return;

        LOG(VB_GENERAL, LOG_ERR,
            "User defined SuspendCommand failed, falling back to "
            "alternative methods.");
    }

    if (m_power && m_power->IsFeatureSupported(MythPower::FeatureSuspend))
        m_power->RequestFeature(MythPower::FeatureSuspend);
}

void ExitPrompter::DoStandby()
{
    GetMythMainWindow()->IdleTimeout();
}

void ExitPrompter::HandleExit()
{
    // HACK IsFrontendOnly() triggers a popup if there is no BE connection.
    // We really don't need that right now. This hack prevents it.
    gContext->SetDisableEventPopup(true);

    // first of all find out, if this is a frontend only host...
    bool frontendOnly = gCoreContext->IsFrontendOnly();

    // HACK Undo the hack, just in case we _don't_ quit:
    gContext->SetDisableEventPopup(false);

    // how do you want to quit today?
    bool allowExit     = false;
    bool allowReboot   = false;
    bool allowShutdown = false;
    bool allowStandby  = false;
    bool allowSuspend  = false;

    bool haveshutdown = !m_haltCommand.isEmpty();
    bool havereboot   = !m_rebootCommand.isEmpty();
    bool havesuspend  = !m_suspendCommand.isEmpty();

#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    haveshutdown = false;
    havereboot   = false;
    havesuspend  = false;
#endif

    if (m_power)
    {
        havereboot   |= m_power->IsFeatureSupported(MythPower::FeatureRestart);
        haveshutdown |= m_power->IsFeatureSupported(MythPower::FeatureShutdown);
        havesuspend  |= m_power->IsFeatureSupported(MythPower::FeatureSuspend);
    }

    switch (gCoreContext->GetNumSetting("OverrideExitMenu", 0))
    {
        case 0:
            allowExit = true;
            if (frontendOnly)
                allowShutdown = haveshutdown;
            break;
        case 1:
            allowExit = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            allowExit = true;
            allowShutdown = haveshutdown;
            break;
        case 3:
            allowExit     = true;
            allowReboot   = havereboot;
            allowShutdown = haveshutdown;
            break;
        case 4:
            allowShutdown = haveshutdown;
            break;
        case 5:
            allowReboot   = havereboot;
            break;
        case 6:
            allowReboot   = havereboot;
            allowShutdown = haveshutdown;
            break;
        case 7:
            allowStandby  = true;
            break;
        case 8:
            allowSuspend  = havesuspend;
            break;
        case 9:
            allowExit = true;
            allowSuspend  = havesuspend;
            break;
    }

    MythScreenStack *ss = GetMythMainWindow()->GetStack("popup stack");
    auto *dlg = new MythDialogBox(tr("Do you really want to exit MythTV?"), ss,
                                  "exit prompt");

    if (!dlg->Create())
    {
        LOG(VB_GENERAL, LOG_ERR, "Can't create Exit Prompt dialog?");
        delete dlg;
        DoQuit();
        return;
    }

    dlg->AddButton(QCoreApplication::translate("(Common)", "No"));
    if (allowExit)
        dlg->AddButton(tr("Yes, Exit now"), SLOT(DoQuit()));
    if (allowReboot)
        dlg->AddButton(tr("Yes, Exit and Reboot"), SLOT(ConfirmReboot()));
    if (allowShutdown)
        dlg->AddButton(tr("Yes, Exit and Shutdown"), SLOT(ConfirmHalt()));
    if (allowStandby)
        dlg->AddButton(tr("Yes, Enter Standby Mode"), SLOT(DoStandby()));
    if (allowSuspend)
        dlg->AddButton(tr("Yes, Suspend"), SLOT(ConfirmSuspend()));

    // This is a hack so that the button clicks target the correct slot:
    dlg->SetReturnEvent(this, QString());

    ss->AddScreen(dlg);
}

void ExitPrompter::Confirm(MythPower::Feature Action) const
{
    MythScreenStack *ss = GetMythMainWindow()->GetStack("popup stack");

    QString msg;

    gContext->SetDisableEventPopup(true);
    if (!gCoreContext->IsFrontendOnly())
    {
      // this is the only case where a prompt should be shown
      msg.prepend(tr("Mythbackend is running on this system. "));

      auto *dlg = new MythConfirmationDialog(ss, msg);

      if (!dlg->Create())
      {
          delete dlg;
          DoQuit();
          return;
      }

      if (Action == MythPower::FeatureShutdown)
          connect(dlg, &MythConfirmationDialog::haveResult, this, &ExitPrompter::DoHalt);
      else if (Action == MythPower::FeatureRestart)
          connect(dlg, &MythConfirmationDialog::haveResult, this, &ExitPrompter::DoReboot);
      else if (Action == MythPower::FeatureSuspend)
          connect(dlg, &MythConfirmationDialog::haveResult, this, &ExitPrompter::DoSuspend);

      ss->AddScreen(dlg);
    }
    else 
    {
      // no prompts required, take a specific action required
      // calling these exitprompter functions with (true) fails build
      if (Action == MythPower::FeatureShutdown)
          DoHalt(true);
      else if (Action == MythPower::FeatureRestart)
          DoReboot(true);
      else if (Action == MythPower::FeatureSuspend)
          DoSuspend(true);
    }

    gContext->SetDisableEventPopup(false);

}
```

I have already tried adding `const` to the end of the DoHalt (etc) functions like:
`void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(const bool Confirmed) const`
`void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(const bool Confirmed) const`
`void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(const bool Confirmed) const`

But this just gives me a different error during build like:

```
cd mythshutdown/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/runner/work/mythtv/mythtv/mythtv/programs/mythshutdown/mythshutdown.pro QMAKE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake ) && make -f Makefile 
exitprompt.cpp:39:6: error: prototype for ‘void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(bool) const’ does not match any in class ‘ExitPrompter’
 void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(const bool Confirmed) const
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from exitprompt.cpp:6:0:
exitprompt.h:14:10: error: candidate is: void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(bool)
Makefile:4570: recipe for target 'obj/exitprompt.o' failed
     void DoHalt(bool Confirmed = true);
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/runner/work/mythtv/mythtv/mythtv/programs/mythfrontend'
          ^~~~~~
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'sub-mythfrontend-make_first' failed
exitprompt.cpp:70:6: error: prototype for ‘void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(bool) const’ does not match any in class ‘ExitPrompter’
 void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(const bool Confirmed) const
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from exitprompt.cpp:6:0:
exitprompt.h:15:10: error: candidate is: void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(bool)
     void DoReboot(bool Confirmed = true);
          ^~~~~~~~
exitprompt.cpp:100:6: error: prototype for ‘void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(bool) const’ does not match any in class ‘ExitPrompter’
 void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(const bool Confirmed) const
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from exitprompt.cpp:6:0:
exitprompt.h:17:10: error: candidate is: void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(bool)
     void DoSuspend(bool Confirmed = true);
          ^~~~~~~~~
exitprompt.cpp: In member function ‘void ExitPrompter::Confirm(MythPower::Feature) const’:
exitprompt.cpp:268:22: error: passing ‘const ExitPrompter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
           DoHalt(true);
                      ^
In file included from exitprompt.cpp:6:0:
exitprompt.h:14:10: note:   in call to ‘void ExitPrompter::DoHalt(bool)’
     void DoHalt(bool Confirmed = true);
          ^~~~~~
exitprompt.cpp:270:24: error: passing ‘const ExitPrompter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
           DoReboot(true);
                        ^
In file included from exitprompt.cpp:6:0:
exitprompt.h:15:10: note:   in call to ‘void ExitPrompter::DoReboot(bool)’
     void DoReboot(bool Confirmed = true);
          ^~~~~~~~
exitprompt.cpp:272:25: error: passing ‘const ExitPrompter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
           DoSuspend(true);
                         ^
In file included from exitprompt.cpp:6:0:
exitprompt.h:17:10: note:   in call to ‘void ExitPrompter::DoSuspend(bool)’
     void DoSuspend(bool Confirmed = true);
          ^~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [obj/exitprompt.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sub-mythfrontend-make_first] Error 2
```

I don't know C++ (I though the change I was making was fairly simple!) very well at all so I need some precise help.

Thanks

Comment: Adding `const` should work, I think you need to show exactly what change you made, and what was the error after you made that change.

Comment: edit original question to include error message when changing functions to be `const`

Comment: OK that's simple enough, you need to add `const` in two places, in the function definition (which it seems you did) and also in the function declaration (which is likely in some header file). This is normal for C++, for many items you have a declaration and a definition, and they both should match.

Comment: Thanks - that was it